# Looking for a book where a boy starts volunteering at a vet's office after school

Tags: identification-request

There's a boy who wants to work at a vet's office, although I don't think his family/father was in favor of it.  One story that stands out in my memory is helping a deaf white kitten (possibly albino) get healthy, and then it gets adopted by a truck driver/delivery man.  The setting gives me a vague 50s feel, possibly Mid-west or New England-y?

I read this book in school, probably 4th-6th grade (~1990).  May have been a Newbery winner/honor book but I can't be 100% sure.

Searching google/goodreads/here hasn't turned up anything so far.

Thank you!